# How to launch internal application from internal website on chrome?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, iis

I've been requested to create a button to launch a java desktop application that will be downloaded on the client machine otherwise return some message. The project owner wants to run the application on chrome, we're using C# in an MVC project. Our network administrators will not let us put java on any of the server's so we have to try and manually open the application.

I've attempted using href with a file protocol like: file://C://etc, file://c:\, file:///c://etc. I've also tried using system.diagnostics and starting the process that way. I've been able to get these to work when running the website locally but once its deployed to the server it can no longer access the client folders correctly.

```
<li onclick="onOpen()">Test</li>

<a href="file://C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Test.lnk">link</a>


function onOpen() {
      $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Test","Home")',
      data: { },
      success: function(data){ alert('Success!')},
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert 
(xhr.responseText); }
      });
    }

public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = 
"C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Test.lnk";
        //process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
        return null;
    }
```

The main goal is to open the application from the web page, we've already added a button to the application to link back to the web page. The idea is to make it simple for the users, where they don't feel like they're leaving the website.

Comment: This is not gonna work. You do not have access to the client pc from the website. If you start a process it will run on the server.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of for the process attempt. What about other possibilities?

Comment: Let your desktop app configure custom URL schema https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa767914 and then embed the corresponding links in your web page will trigger the application launch. Sites like GitHub use such approaches which you can analyze further.